# Covert List into non-indexed Vector in R

Tags: r, list, vector, type-conversion

I have a List in the following form

```
[[1]]
[1] "2014-09-26"

[[2]]
[1] "2013-09-27"

[[3]]
[1] "2012-09-28"

[[4]]
character(0)
```

But I need it in the following form of the following code

```
end_dates <- c("2014-09-26", "2013-09-27", "2012-09-28", "")
```

I can't just type in these values as they are calculated from another set of data, which is then used in subsequent code, which fails when I use the List and works when I use a Vector.

Comment: @akrun's is the proper way. this is an alternate `gsub("character(0)", "", as.vector(my_list, mode="character"), fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: @hrbrmstr I think you meant something like `as.Date(as.vector(lst, mode="numeric"), origin = "1970-01-01")`, no?

Comment: I wasn't sure if the OP wanted actual dates or strings. it wasn't clear.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I was testing your suggestion with akruns data (`Date` class), but if the data are just characters, then your suggestion will work.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to have missing values as `NA` instead of `''`.

Using a `if/else` condition, we replace `list` elements with `length` equal to 0 as `NA` and then use `do.call('c',..`

```
  end_dates <- do.call('c', lapply(lst, function(x) if(length(x)==0) NA else x))
  end_dates
  #[1] "2014-09-26" "2013-09-27" "2012-09-28" NA          
  str(end_dates)
  #Date[1:4], format: "2014-09-26" "2013-09-27" "2012-09-28" NA
```

#### data

```
 lst <- list(structure(16339, class = "Date"), structure(15975, class = "Date"), 
structure(15611, class = "Date"), structure(numeric(0), class = "Date"))
```

Comment: the c inside do.call needs quotes 'c'

Comment: @Sölvi  If you have already defined `c` as a object name in the global space, it needs quote.  Otherwise, it will work without that.  But, I edited it in case somebody accidentally have a object `c`

Comment: You are right, I had another object called c already in my environment.